# reading a common string in python

Tags: python

Hi i want to read and display strB's line number  which is a common string and follows immediately in file after reading  string A through string A's line number

```
i am a common line
i am a common line
i am a common line
i am a common line
defghijklt 
I am a unique line 
jaslkdjaldjsadsajdlakjdasldj
spjpsijgpigjpijgjfdpgfdpgjdppdfjgdpfpi
jspijdfpgfdjgfdijgdfpjgdfpijgdfijfdoifdjpi
jgdfjfdpijfdpijgdgdjfdfjgidjgfdoijdfojgdfoijfdoo
jgdfoijfdijfdoifdjgfdoijgfdoijfdojfdoijfdojfdoifjdogfdjoi
i am a common line    
i am a common line
ueowueoodsjpdogfdpofdpofdpdfigdpgdifgdifdiikpkpjfdspjf
```

this is my code :

```
strB = 'i am common line'
strA = 'I am a unique line'

input_file = open('mynewfile.txt', 'r')
with input_file as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile):
        if strA in line:
            print num
            for num in range (num, num+12):
                if strB in line:
                    print num
```

please suggest what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a flag:

```
input_file = open('mynewfile.txt', 'r')
with input_file as myFile:
    foundA = False
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile):
        if strA in line:
            foundA = True
            print num

        # Only look for `strB` if `strA` has been seen first
        if foundA and strB in line:
            print num
            break  # stop reading the file.
```

Alternatively, nest the loops, to search for *each* `strB`-after-`strA` event:

```
input_file = open('mynewfile.txt', 'r')
with input_file as myFile:
    enumerated = enumerate(myFile):
    for num, line in enumerated:
        if strA in line:
            print num
            for num, line in enumerated:
                if strB in line:
                    print num
                    break  # search for next strA
```

Comment: @MartinPieters  Hi Martin ,i don't see the second string line number still displayed . It shows the first string displayed although i like your answer. only first line number is getting displayed. this is in context to  the first code added by you

Comment: Are you 100% certain the second line is in the file? Try printing `repr(line)` in a few places to see what is being read.

Comment: oh , yeah the line got deleted from the file ......yes its working i am sorry .....your code is all good